# In Sunstorm, why is the Pacific Ocean west of Perth?

Tags: time-odyssey

Chapter 49 of the second book of the Time Odyssey trilogy is called ''Pacific'', and begins 200 km west of Perth. The characters are under "the Pacific sun".

Is this a hint at some massive change in Earth's geography as a result of the actions of the Firstborn, or for some other reason?

I find it hard to imagine it was a mistake, since Clarke lived most of his life on the shores of the Indian Ocean.

Comment: The book was "co-authored" by Arthur C. Clarke. Maybe Sir Arthur didn't read it? I mean, maybe he didn't read that part?

Comment: Maybe "Pacific sun" was a typo for "pacific sun" which would be a sort of poetic alternative to "quiet sun" as in low sunspot activity?

Comment: You're sure it's Perth, Australia, and not Perth, Scotland? (No, I haven't read the books.) Putting Scotland in the Pacific Ocean would be only a minor change in Earth's geography. Well, compared with moving Australia.

Comment: @user14111  Good point - Scotland would be easier to move! The Prime Minister of Australia hosts the occasion. Sounds like we are stuck with speculation without any explanation in the books or by the authors :(  I prefer your first speculation!

Comment: @user14111 There's an even easier answer than that. The Indian Ocean is, officially, bounded on the West and East by the Southernmost points of Africa and Tasmania, respectively. So, just move Tasmania West, to be about in line with Thailand and Cambodia, and then you have a few hundred kilometers of Pacific Ocean to the West of Perth!

Answer (score -2):

It seems to me that the easiest and simplest solution is to assume that in the era of the story the Pacific Ocean is defined as extending to the west of Australia.  The borders of the oceans are rather arbitrary since there is really only one world ocean.  Since the Pacific Ocean is larger than all the other oceans maybe in this setting the Pacific Ocean is arbitrarily definded to extend around the world.

Comment: That seems like over-complicated retcon. The book is set in the mid-21st century, so barring an explanation by an author or publisher, I am putting it down to an editor's oversight.

Comment: @Qsigma - Agreed. If we're going to introduce our own fanfic to answer the question, you might as well just say that in this world the names "Pacific Ocean" and "Indian Ocean" are reversed or that it's a weird mirror universe where everything's backwards or that the speaker is clearly having a stroke.